# Amazon Web Services - Redirect www. traffic to non www

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to  301 redirect www.socholotiukmma.com to socholotiukmma.com

I've followed this tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/ but it's not working.

I'm assuming it's because I'm redirecting to an https site. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a `.htaccess` file.

Create a file called `.htaccess` and put this inside your document root (i.e. the main directory where you put your website files):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.socholotiukmma\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://socholotiukmma.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This should then redirect everybody going to http://www.socholotiukmma.com to http://socholotiukmma.com

If you want to redirect everybody to https://socholotiukmma.com then just change the URL in the final line of the file.